# Background music problems in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background

I have problem with this code:

```
-(void)playSong
{
    // ...
    NSLog(@"playing %i", currentSONG);
    VKAudio* song = [audios objectAtIndex:currentSONG];
    if (player == nil) { // create player object when first called
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[self urlForVKAudio:song]];
        [player play];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]; // turn on in background
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleAVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
    }
    else {
        [player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:
        [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[self urlForVKAudio:song]]];
        [player play]; // <- this is not working when phone is blocked & screen is off
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when I switch into bg mode while playing music it is playing to end of the current item, but the next item isn't playing, so in background mode method

```
[player play];
```

doesn't do anything... What am I doing wrong? (bg music mode is on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have your AudioSession set up correctly, but don't activate it.

This is what I'm using:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: thanks a lot! have no time to check now, but I'll report the results when possible!